# How to Use "gradlew" in teminal of android studio in Linux

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-14.04

There are "gradlew" and "gradle.bat" in the root dir of project!,I can use "gradlew" in Mac and WIndows ,but can not use it in Linux! What should I do to use it? Thank you for tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably doesn't have executable permissions. Try `chmod +x gradlew` and then `./gradlew` should work normally